# Windows Server 2012 MSMQ Issue

Tags: cluster-computing, msmq, windows-server-2012, failover

I have setup a failover cluster in Windows Server 2012 which contains two nodes. I have used Microsoft MSMQ for communication. If I try the write on the queue remotely using the node name `DIRECT=OS:mymachine\private$\MyQueueQueue` then I am able to write on it but when I use the virtual IP of the cluster then the message got stuck in Outgoing Queues

1. I have disabled the firewall.
2. I am able to telnet to the MSMQ port `1801` from node IPs but not able to telnet with the virtual IP which is used by failover cluster

Comment: My queres are not the part of the cluster

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue, did you find a solution in the while? Thanks